# Sql syntax error near WHERE

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have this query for updating a row but im getting a sql syntax error "near WHERE" but neither me or my friend can figure out what the problem is.

rowstandard is a string specifying which row to select. and row is an array with the updated values that are supposed to be UPDATED.

```
 query = "UPDATE  "+ tablename +" WHERE " + FirstColumn + " = '" + rowstandard + "' VALUES("+row+")";
```

Comment: you forgot the `SET` keyword -- the columns you want to update.

Comment: You are mixing `UPDATE` with `INSERT`

Comment: Also related: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you'll end up with something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable WHERE cname = 'dsfsdf' VALUES('dfssdffs');
```

That's not right. It needs to be like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET cname = 'dfsafdsf' WHERE cname = 'foobar';
```

Comment: but in your example your only changing one column, i need mine to change all the columns dynamically since different tables have differet amounts of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your update statement should be done like this:

```
query = "UPDATE " + tablename + " SET " + columnname + " = '" + value + "' WHERE " + colmnname2 " = '" + value2 + "'";
```